# Print based on one line condition when applying a function to a data frame Python

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, printing, apply

I have the following dataframe and I would like to print only the columns that have a missing  Value.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'col_A' : [1,2,3,4],
                   'col_B' : [1,2,np.NaN,4]})
```

Function to find NaN's:

```
def num_missing(x):
    return sum(x.isnull())
```

while the print without the condition works:

```
print( data.apply(num_missing, axis=0))
```

Output:

```
col_A    0
col_B    1
dtype: int64
```

Desired Output:

```
col_B    1
dtype: int64
```

I tried to print with the one line if statement ... but I am doing something wrong with the syntax

```
print( data.apply(num_missing, axis=0) if data.apply(num_missing, axis=0)> 0)
```

I also tried the below if statement which is not working either:

```
 if data.apply(num_missing, axis=0) >0:
        print( data.apply(num_missing, axis=0) )
```

Could you please provide both solution and and explain me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC I think you need something like this

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'col_A' : [1,2,3,4],
                   'col_B' : [1,2,np.NaN,4]})
#finding null values in columns and if atleat one null value is present printing it.
print(data.columns.values[data.isnull().any()])
['col_B']
```

Try this

```
print(data.isnull().sum()[data.isnull().any()])
col_B    1
dtype: int64
```

For OP

```
if data.apply(num_missing, axis=0)>0:
    print('Yay')
```

Since the line `data.apply(num_missing, axis=0)>0` produces a series not a single boolean value. If you use if statement for a `series` bool column, it will throw the traceback as:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-282-12bc35218d0e> in <module>()
----> 1 if data.apply(num_missing, axis=0)>0:
      2     print('Yay')

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1119         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1120                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
-> 1121                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
   1122 
   1123     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

The above if statement should be used along with either of `a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`. So, at the end you get a boolean series with length of number of columns. Which is redundant. So better use the above mentioned ways instead of sticking to if statement.

If you still want to execute inside a if statement. Try this:

```
if (data.apply(num_missing, axis=0)>0).any():
    print(data.apply(num_missing, axis=0)[data.apply(num_missing, axis=0)>0])
```

If there is no NaN values in any column then it would be helpful, otherwise the if statement will be redundant. Thank you.

Comment: Yes but this is not going to give the number of missing. + I would like to understand the if one line statement.

Comment: @A.Papa I have updated it. Please check and let me if know this worked for you.

Comment: Hi Sandeep, This indeed works. Any idea how I should code it to work  with the if statement?

Comment: Thnaks @Sandeep Kadapa, your solution is so much faster!

Comment: @A.Papa Glad to help.